# makefile recipe failed when started as a C# process

Tags: c#, process, cmd, makefile

I have a makefile and when I run this makefile on a windows console (cmd), it perfectly completes all the recipes.

However, when i run this script on a .NET process as shown below, it fails on a certain part:

```
     Process featureExtractionProcess = new Process();

     featureExtractionProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "make.exe";

     featureExtractionProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "all";
     featureExtractionProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     featureExtractionProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     featureExtractionProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = _runLocation;
     featureExtractionProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     Logger.Debug("Starting feature extraction in " + _runLocation);
     featureExtractionProcess.Start();
     StreamReader sr = featureExtractionProcess.StandardOutput;
     string output = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

The constant error is:

"Makefile:275: recipe for target 'list' failed"

the recipe "list" is like this:

```
list:

    mkdir -p lists
    rm -f tmp
    for spkr in $(TRAINSPKR); do \
        for lab in labels/full/$${spkr}/*.lab; do \
            if [ -s $${lab} -a -s labels/mono/$${spkr}/`basename $${lab}` -a -s cmp/$${spkr}/`basename $${lab} .lab`.cmp ]; then \
                sed -e "s/.* //g" $${lab} >> tmp; \
            fi; \
        done; \
    done
    sort -u tmp > lists/full.list
    rm -f tmp
```

The make ends just after the loop and does not execute sort.

Why is there a difference in behavior between cmd and C# process?

Comment: Without viewing makefile we can only guess reason of the error. Please, provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, edited the question

Comment: Result of the loop is a result of the last command executed within loop. It seems that `sed` command is failed for some reason. Probably, error message for that fails is written to `stderr`, but you redirect only `stdout` in your C# code. I am unsure, but difference between running make from `cmd` and C# (as a process) could be using different shells, which interprets make receipts. Or different environment for the shell (such as environment variables).

Comment: thanks, redirecting standard error worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tsyvarev, I have found a solution. I redirected standard error in addition to the standard output:

```
featureExtractionProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

and make scripts completes in a C# process without any problem

Comment: So simple redirection of `stderr` helps to make *itself*? In my comment to the question I expected this would only *helps to understand problem* in the make process, not to completely decide the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yes, without any error on the log, the process completed